# how to delete a key in a list of dicts?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
def get_all_cust_info():
    """function displays data as a list of dict of base  data"""
    reader = csv.DictReader(open("base data.csv", "rb"))
    all_rows = list()
    for row in reader:
    all_rows.append(row)
    return all_rows
```

first line output of get_all_cust_info().

```
   [{'totcust': '2', 'delfee': '1308', 'bskt_bnd': '0', 'distribution ': '>1', 'totords': '199', 'netsales': '1851'}, .......]
```

I want to create a new function which deletes keys('delfee' and 'netsales') and also add new key 'order value'.This is what I have done

```
    def cust_state():
        s = get_all_cust_info()
        for d in s:
            if d.has_key('delfee'):
               del d['delfee']
               print s
```

But I am getting this error.

```
  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

Would really appreciate help on this.

Comment: Don't use `has_key`. `foo.has_key('bar')` has been spelled `'bar' in foo` for a long time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if s.has_key('delfee'):
```

should be:

```
if d.has_key('delfee'):
```

```
def cust_state():
        s = get_all_cust_info()
        for d in s:
            if 'delfree' in d:
                del d['delfree']
            if 'netsales' in d:
                del d['netsales']
            d['ordervalue'] = something
        return s
```

Comment: yh sorry that was a typo

Comment: It works but only for the first line of output but not for the whole ouput

Comment: What do you mean? I test it it works right. Could you post your code and let me see what is going wrong? @SafeKhan

Comment: I mean get_cust_info() gives me say following first two outputs(multiple dicts in a list): [{'totcust': '2', 'delfee': '1308', 'bskt_bnd': '0', 'distribution ': '>1', 'totords': '199', 'netsales': '1851'}, {'totcust': '1', 'delfee': '317', 'bskt_bnd': '0', 'distribution ': '0.75-1', 'totords': '49', 'netsales': '475'},  and so ,,,]

Comment: this is the code :                                                    `def cust_state():
    s = get_all_cust_info()
    for d in s:
        if 'delfee' in d:
            del d['delfee']
        if 'netsales' in d:
            del d['netsales']
        d['order value'] = 0    
 
        return s `

Comment: Where do you put the `return s`? It should be put out of the scope of `for`. See my updated answer.@SafeKhan

Comment: and now cust_state() gives me this output:[{'totcust': '2', 'bskt_bnd': '0', 'distribution ': '>1', 'order value': 0, 'totords': '199'}, {'totcust': '1', 'delfee': '317', 'bskt_bnd': '0', 'distribution ': '0.75-1', 'totords': '49', 'netsales': '475'},..]

Comment: one more little thing: if I want to change the value of dicts as not being a string but an integer, how would I do that?

Comment: In python, you can assign any type of objects to a variable. `dict[key] = 1` no matter what type the previous value is. Or if you mean the `dict[1] = something`. It is also OK. The key just need to be hashable.@SafeKhan